# Модули, устанавливаемые извне

Tags: javascript, phonegap, cordova, модули, ecmascript

Доброго времени суток.

Есть HTML5 приложение (PhoneGap/Cordova), в которое нужно добавить модульную систему.

Реализовать следующие возможности:

```
1) Установка модулей извне по ссылке (именно установка)
2) Модули могут использовать только API, предоставляемый приложением
```

Вариант с хранением модулей в FS не годится, ибо
а) Засоряет диск файлами б) Возможна подмена файлов

Остаётся localStorage, cookie и другие мне не известные хранилища

Comment: С хранилищем решить можно, самое главное - 2)

Comment: в качестве хранилища еще можно indexeddb

Comment: @username.ak как дела с совместимостью с Cordova 2.9.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот, вроде оно: https://github.com/natevw/evel

Тут готовое-решение обертка вокруг iframe и eval, которая защищает от инъекции кода.

У неё есть, конечно, свои способы обхода, но их постепенно исправляют.

Решение заключается в том что скрипт максимально изолируется: выполняется в отдельном фрейме, удаляются опасные функции и создаются свои реализации некоторых.

Работает везде с поддержкой ES5

Comment: Ссылка  не является ответом,  лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.